# If X~Exp(λ), what is the expected value of Y=X²?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I am trying to compute this using the integral definition of expected value but I don't think I am doing it right as I am getting a very hard integral that I can not solve.

When computing $\mathbb{E}[X]$, I used the formula
$$\int_0^\infty x\,(1/λ)\exp\{-x/λ\}\,\text{d}x$$ 
and solved it using integration by parts, with $u = x$ and $dv=(1/λ)e^{-x/λ}$. But I can not figure out the integration by parts for $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ because of the $\exp\{-x^2/λ\}$ when calculating the expected value of $Y$.

Comment: Show what you tried so that we can identify where you went wrong. The correct integral is *very* easy, yielding to obvious application of routine integration methods. How did you do $E(X)$?

Comment: I was doing the integral of x^2(1/λ)exp(-x^2/λ)  and have no clue how to solve this. For E(X), it was easy to do because there was no x^2.

Comment: If it was easy to do E(X) it should not be at all difficult for you to explain what it was you did. What approach did you use?

Comment: E[X] = integral from 0 to infinity of x*(1/λ)*e^(x/λ) and did this using integration by parts, with u = x and dv=(1/λ)*e^(x/λ) .  But I can not figure out the integration by parts because of the e^(x^2/λ) when calculating the expected value of Y.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that your integrand for $E(X^2)$ is wrong (please edit it into your question). How did you decide there should be an $x^2$ in the exponent? There are two ways to get $E(Y)=E(X^2)$: either find the distribution of $Y$ and then the expectation of it, or find the expectation of $X^2$ "directly". \[Are you aware of the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)?]

Comment: @Xi'an I think that's sufficiently detailed guidance to count as an answer for this question, if you'd like to post it as one.

Comment: @Glen_b: thank you, I moved the comment into an indication of an answer!

Answer (score 5):

Following [@Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b)'s remarks, I think your issue is less with integration than with properly defining the integral:
$$[X^2]=∫^∞_0 x^2 \exp(−x/λ)/λ\,\text{d}x$$
rather than this erroneous version:
$$[X^2]=∫^∞_0 x^2 \exp(−x^2/λ)/λ\,\text{d}x.$$
Once this straightened, (one or two) integration(s) by part should become obvious.